# Database's URL changes from /config/application doesn't affect my output #Micronaut

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, consul, micronaut

I'm new to this micronaut and micro-service stuffs. Here's my problem:

I have 2 databases named "consul" and "consul_1" in Postgres. Both of them have one table named "trials" with same columns name(name : varchar and age : int) but different data.

And I have one simple application with REST API using Micronaut to show my table data. I heard about this *Centralized Configuration* or *Distributed Configuration*, then i  tried to build the configuration inside Consul's /config/application KV in yaml format.

My configuration is actually working. I can show the table's data and a property's (named foo.bar) value correctly. However, when I changed the datasource URL from ../consul to ../consul_1 and foo.bar value from *halo* to *hai*, hitting /refresh endpoint, then tried to show my table data and foo.bar's value again, my table data stayed the same but the foo.bar changed.

**UPDATE**
I've tried adding `@Refreshable` annotation from micronaut in the repository, the controller class, and the POJO class out of curiosity, but none of that working. I've also tried removing `@CurrentSession` and `@PersistenceObject` from repository implementation (because I thought this was the cause) but nothing happened either.

I've tried using `getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll()`, try setting up 2 datasources then using `@Transactional("${foo.bar}"` (the datasources name was the same with foo.bar value) and `@CurrentSession("${foo.bar})` in hope to refreshing the connection. but these didn't work

Micronaut version : 1.2.1;
JVM version : 1.8.0

here are my current code:

***REST Controller***

```java
@Controller("/control")
public class control {

    @Inject
    public inter Inter;

    @Get("/")
    public String test(){
        System.out.println(Inter.string());
        return String.valueOf(Inter.showAll());
    }
}
```

***Repository interface***

```java
public interface inter {

    List<Trials> showAll();

    String string();
}
```

***Repository Implementation***

```java
@Singleton
@Refreshable
public class imple implements inter {

    @Inject
    @CurrentSession
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Value("${foo.bar}")
    private String s;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Trials> showAll(){
        String qstring = "select u from Trials u";
        TypedQuery<Trials> query = entityManager.createQuery(qstring, Trials.class);
        List<Trials> hasil = query.getResultList();
        return hasil;
    }

    @Override
    public String string(){
        return s;
    }
}
```

***Trials Class***

```java
@Entity(name = "Trials")
@Table
public class Trials {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "age")
    private Integer age;

    public Trials() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try{
            return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(this);
        }catch (JsonProcessingException e){return "failed";}
    }
}
```

***application.yml***

```yaml
micronaut:
  application:
    name: consul-config-exc
---
consul:
  client:
    registration:
      enabled: true
---
endpoints:
 all:
  enabled: true
  sensitive: false
 stop:
  enabled: false
```

***bootstrap.yml***

```yaml
micronaut:
  application:
    name: consul-config-exc
  config-client:
    enabled: true

consul:
  client:
    config:
      format: YAML
    defaultZone: "${CONSUL_HOST:localhost}:${CONSUL_PORT:8500}"
```

and lastly, ***/config/application*** in consul key/value

```yaml
foo:
 bar: halo
---
datasources:
 default:
  url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/consul
  username: postgres
  password: root
  driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
---
jpa:
 default:
  entity-scan:
   - "consul.config.exc.domain"
```

what i want is when i change "consul" to "consul_1", i only need to hit /refresh endpoint which provided by micronaut then the database changes. But currently, i need to restart my application for it to changes.

Can anyone tell me what did i do wrong and tell me how to make it work? Thank you very much and sorry for bad English.

Comment: "However, when I changed the datasource URL from ../consul to ../consul_1 and foo.bar value from halo to hai, hitting /refresh endpoint, then tried to show my table data and foo.bar's value again, my table data stayed the same but the foo.bar changed." - That is because your `imple` class that has the `foo.bar` value in it is `@Refreshable`.  The database connection isn't.

Comment: @M.Deinum I see thank you for your answer. I'll try to find a way to refresh the connection.